# How to Implement Paging through JQuery in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, paging

I am developing a site in which i need the search result should be displayed 10 by 10. For that the result should be displayed through JQuery. Please Help. Any Code snippets or references will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

there are some cool jquery-plugin out there:

- http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/pager/#examples
- http://www.j-dee.com/2008/12/22/jquery-pager-plugin/
- http://encosia.com/2008/08/20/easily-build-powerful-client-side-ajax-paging-using-jquery/
- http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/20/simplepager---jquery-paging-plugin--updated